# Change background of GLFWwindow on key press

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, visual-c++, glfw

I want to be able to cycle through 5 background colours when I press the "B" key. Right now I can only change my colour to red. I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way. Any help would be appreciated.

```
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {

if (key == GLFW_KEY_B && action == GLFW_PRESS)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                break;

            case 1:
                glClearColor(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                break;

            case 2:
                glClearColor(0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 1.0);
                break;

            case 3:
                glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                break;

            case 4:
                glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                return;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You're close. Use a global variable as counter. if the key equals B increment the counter, and then switch on the new value of the counter to run the correct `glClearColor` function.

Answer (score 0):

When you press the B key, cycle is started and you see the last color, you need to put the test of press key into the cycle. Like this:

```
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      Readkey(key);
       if (key == GLFW_KEY_B && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        {
        switch (i)
            {
              case 0:
                glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                break;

              case 1:
                glClearColor(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                break;

            case 2:
                glClearColor(0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 1.0);
                break;

            case 3:
                glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                break;

            case 4:
                glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                return;
           }
       }
    }
```